# Swift iOS -Constraint isn't animating even though view.layoutIfNeeded() is called

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uiviewanimation

I have a rounded likeButton that is behind a rounded moreButton. The likeButton is pinned to the centerX and centerY of the moreButton. When I press the moreButton I want to animate the likeButton 200 points above the moreButton.

I use a `NSLayoutConstraint` to keep track of the likeButton's centerY and to make changes to it. When I call `UIView.animate` and inside it's closure I call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` the view isn't updating.

```
@objc func moreButtonTapped(){

    likeButtonCenterY?.isActive = false
    likeButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.moreButton.centerYAnchor, constant: -200)
    likeButtonCenterY?.isActive = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

**Where am I going wrong?**

```
let moreButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "more"), for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .red
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

let likeButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "like"), for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .blue
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    return button
}()

var likeButtonCenterY: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    setAnchors()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    moreButton.layer.cornerRadius = moreButton.frame.size.width / 2
    likeButton.layer.cornerRadius = likeButton.frame.size.width / 2
}

@objc func moreButtonTapped(){

    likeButtonCenterY?.isActive = false
    likeButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.moreButton.centerYAnchor, constant: -200)
    likeButtonCenterY?.isActive = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func setAnchors(){
    view.addSubview(likeButton)
    view.addSubview(moreButton)

    moreButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    moreButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
    moreButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    moreButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    likeButtonCenterY = likeButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: moreButton.centerYAnchor)
    likeButtonCenterY?.isActive = true

    likeButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: moreButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    likeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    likeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@objc func moreButtonTapped(){

likeButtonCenterY?.isActive = false
likeButtonCenterY = likeButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.moreButton.centerYAnchor, constant: -200)
likeButtonCenterY?.isActive = true

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
}
```

You have forgotten to write `likeButtonCenterY =`

Comment: oh shoot your right. I forgot to add in likeButtonCenterY =. You should adjust your answer to note that I need to add in likeButtonCenterY =. Everything else is the same. I'll accept it if you update it. It's easier to show that I overlooked it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are activating/deactivating multiple constraints at the same time (like a batch), you might need to override the `updateConstraints()` method. More information is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622512-updateconstraints

Basically your code in the `moreButtonTapped()` will go in the overridden implementation of the `updateConstraints()` method. Don't forget to call `super()` in the last line of the method.

Then your animation code should look like look like:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: Ill try it now. Thanks

Comment: The problem was I forgot to add in likeButtonCenterY =. I'm going to upvote your answer because even though it didn't answer the question, you showed me something I didn't know.

Comment: Why? If he doesn't have any custom code in `updateConstraints` then this is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Lance! What I said is indeed true; if you are updating multiple constraints at the same time and removing or adding one causes auto-layout conflicts, then you would need to use `updateConstraints()`. In your case, there are no conflicts so you wouldn't need `updateConstraints()`.